# Why it is not CE when a class implements two interfaces with the same default method and one of the interfaces extends the other one?

Tags: methods, java-8, interface, default

Can someone explain to me why is not a CE in the below snippet of code? The class implements both interfaces which has the same default method, but what is changed when one of the interfaces extends the other one?And also, why i cannot call the print from T1 with  T1.super.print();?

```
interface T1{
    default void print() {System.out.println("T1");}
}



interface T2 extends T1{
    default void print() {System.out.println("T2");}
}

public class Child implements T1,T2{

    public static void main (String... a) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.print();
        T1.super.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `@Override` 2) `T1.super` is not a class - so can't work

Comment: And "CE" does mean what?

Comment: CE means Compiler error

Comment: `T2 extends T1`, hence, `T2.print()` overrides `T1.print()`. So there’s no ambiguity here and `Client` being a subtype of `T2` is not allowed to bypass `T2.print()`. Besides that, it requires a valid `this` to do a `super` call, i.e. the call must be in a constructor or instance method. It can’t be in the `static` main method.

Comment: but Child is also a subtype of T1 because it implements it, no? so why it doesn't give compiler error?